# Kibana меняеть временную зону

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

[image]

Принимаю данные через xml фильтр все даты Logstash принимает все правильно но когда дело доходит до Kibana он меняеть временную зону

Мой config для Logstash

```
 input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
        soap_request => {
                    method => post
                    url => "###"
        headers => {
                    "Content-Type" => "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
                    "SOAPAction" => "###"
                    }
                        body => 'request'               
                    } 
              }
    schedule => { cron => "*/1 * * * * UTC"}
            request_timeout => 60
            codec => multiline {
            pattern => "<m:Document>" 
            negate => "true"
            what => "previous"      
                                }
             }
       }
filter {
     xml {source => "message"
        store_xml => false
         remove_namespaces => "true"
         xpath => [
            "/Document/Number/text()", "number",
            "/Document/Name/text()", "name",
            "/Document/DataRegistration/text()", "dataregistration"
                   ]
          }

        }
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ['localhost:9200']
        index => "sdasu2"
        document_type => "calls2"
        document_id=>"%{number}"
                  }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
            }   
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в часовом поясе. По умолчанию Kibana работает в UTC. Проверьте, совпадает ли часовой пояс в ваших документах ES с часовым поясом Кибаны.

**Management Tab ->Advance Settings ->dateFormat:tz**

Плюс посмотрите [эту дискуссию](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/697)